# How can I replace text after a specific word using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Input file sample.txt

```
some log file entries
some log file entries
Hostname:MyHostName
some log file entries
some log file entries
```

i have to change `MyHostname` string

This commands are not working

```
sed -e 's/^Hostname: .*:/Hostname:mmphate/' sample.txt

sed -e 's/^Hostname: .*$/Hostname:mmphate/' sample.txt
```

Comment: What problems do you have?

Comment: `sed 's/^Hostname:.*/Hostname:mmphate/' file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you can do it literally:

```
sed -e 's/Hostname:MyHostName/Hostname:mmphate/g' sample.txt
```

Or for every line starting by "Hostname:":

```
sed -e 's/^Hostname:.*$/Hostname:mmphate/g' sample.txt
```

If your hostname (mmphate in your example) is within a variable (for example hostname_var), you may execute:

```
sed -e "s/^Hostname:.*$/Hostname:$hostname_var/g" sample.txt
```

**NOTE:** Take care of double quotes in this case.

Comment: but we dont know word after Hostname:

Comment: @MaheshPhate Edited with variable usage

Answer (score 5):

Another simple version

```
sed 's/\(Hostname:\).*/\1mmphate/' sample.txt
```

If you want to use the host name from a shell variable, you can do this.

```
$ export _myhost="My Host Name"
$ sed "s/\(Hostname:\).*/\1${_myhost}/" sample.txt
```

Comment: how can we define variable insted of 1mmphate

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 `:` in your pattern(`Hostname: .*:`). Try this:

```
sed -e 's/^Hostname:.*/Hostname:mmphate/' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with `Perl`:  This will divide the line into two parts, first would be `Hostname:` and second would be rest of the line. First part would be referred as `$1` ,whereas Nth part would be referred as `$N`. Check backreferencing .

```
perl -lnpe 's/(Hostname:)(.*)/$1 blabla/' input
some log file entries
some log file entries
Hostname: blabla
some log file entries
some log file entries
```

Or you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} /Hostname/{$2="blabla"}1' input
```

Comment: Worth to be mentioned that Perl Solution will work OK and work the same in a great variety of machines equipped with Perl ,while sed solutions will work only with GNU Sed (thus will not work on free/open bsd, mac os, etc)